# Batch user input adding new line/haracter at the end of data in txt

Tags: batch-file, user-input

I'm trying to write simple bat script, to take user input data and place it in couple of txt files (configuration files for python program)
But always on the end of placed data in txt, there is new line, like it makes "enter" on the end of placed data. I readed that it's beacause, when user input data in cmd window, he need press "Enter" to pass it, so the key press is also recorded and passed to txt file. I can be wrong with it.
I need to get ride of it in order to data be proper readed.
I didn't figured how to do it.
My code is ugly and mess, but working (except this problem)
I started  making it 3 days ago

```
echo (1) Start
echo (2) Resume session
echo.

set /A "M=10*%ERRORLEVEL:~-1%"
CHOICE /C:12345 /M "Wybierz opcje:"
set /A "M+=%ERRORLEVEL:~-1%

:: Notatka - ERRORLEVELS decreasing
if %M%== 2 goto Resume
if %M%== 1 goto Start

:Start
set /p id= "channel ID:"
set /p sid= "Server ID:"
set /p text= "text:"
set /p time= "time:"

::ID of channel
echo
cd C:\Users\LoveRussia\Documents\DiscordBotClient\automatic-discord-message-main\spam skrypt\1\textfiles
echo %id% > channel.txt

::Link, made with server ID and channel ID
cd C:\Users\LoveRussia\Documents\DiscordBotClient\automatic-discord-message-main\spam skrypt\1\textfiles
echo https://discord.com/channels/%sid%/%id% > channellink.txt

::the message
echo %text%
cd C:\Users\LoveRussia\Documents\DiscordBotClient\automatic-discord-message-main\spam skrypt\1\textfiles
echo %text% > message.txt

::time between messages
echo %time%
cd C:\Users\LoveRussia\Documents\DiscordBotClient\automatic-discord-message-main\spam skrypt\1\textfiles
echo %time% > time.txt

echo Press to proceed
pause

:Resume
::Main process should start now

cd C:\Users\LoveRussia\Documents\DiscordBotClient\automatic-discord-message-main\spam skrypt\1
start py AutoMessage.py
timeout 1 > nul
```

Comment: It's not a new line character, its a line feed character, and it is supposed to be there. If you write a Windows text file and each line does not end with a Carriage Return and Line Feed pair then the file is technically broken. Please explain to us the technical reason why the CRLF pair should not exist at the end of the line(s). BTW it has nothing to do with the end user pressing the `[ENTER]` key, it is correctly included by the `ECHO` command, so if you don't want it, don't use `echo`.

Comment: It should not exist at the end of the line, beacause python program is reading it as part of input data, giving registry errors. Can't edit python program - It's not made by me.
So I need to somehow get ride of CRLF

If using echo cause it, what I should use instead of it?

Comment: The search engine at the top of the page would be a good start!

Comment: @KJ, `timeout 1` and `timeout /T 1` is completely the same, it will wait until the next second multiple, resulting in a delay time of 0 to 1 sec. The line-break is coded as `13` and `10` (`0x0D` and `0x0A` in hex. notation)…

Comment: Try `< nul set /P ="%text%" > "message.txt"`…

Comment: Going forward please only provide a [mcve] of the code you are using that represents your problem. I am stressing minimal. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask] a good question.

Comment: It's much more likely, the error isn't with the l`CRLF`, but with the extra space you introduced into each line. Use `(echo %var%) > file.txt` to avoid the space (I don't think the `CRLF` is a problem at all)

Comment: Compo Thanks, I found some other usefull info
@aschipfl Thank's mate. Didn't knew about that!
Also thank's for < nul set /P ="%text%" > "message.txt"  It worked for me!
Squashman Sorry for that. gonna take care of it better.
Stephan Thank's for help too!